# Qt C++ Delaying QNAM sslErrors signal

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, splash-screen

I have an app with a splash screen that I keep up for 2 seconds using the thread sleep method. In my MianWindow I have a object that listens to the sslErrors signal then calls a slot that displays the ssl error. I don't want that dialog with the errors displaying until after the splash screen has closed. This application has to also be able to run from a network folder.

On my local machine it behaves the way I want it to everytime but on a network drive sometimes the SSL error dialog opens while the splash screen is displayed, so when I click the No button on the dialog (for ignoring the errors) my app crashes :S

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "single_application.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSplashScreen>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QMessageBox>

const QString CSM_VERSION = QString("v1.0i");

class MyInitThread : public QThread
{
protected:
    void run(void)
    {
        this->sleep(2);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) try
{
    bool my_global_bool = true;
    SingleApplication a(argc, argv, "CSM_CYTO_VIEWER_RUN_ONCE");
    a.setProperty("my_global_bool", my_global_bool);
        if (a.isRunning())
        {
            QMessageBox::information(0, "Cyto Viewer " + CSM_VERSION, "Cyto Viewer is already running.");
            return 0;
        }

    //QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QApplication::setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/logo/csm.ico"));
    QApplication::setApplicationName(QString("Cyto Viewer"));
    QApplication::setApplicationVersion(QString(CSM_VERSION));
    //Check if system has a system tray
        if (!QSystemTrayIcon::isSystemTrayAvailable()) {
                 QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Systray"),
                                       QObject::tr("I couldn't detect any system tray "
                                                   "on this system."));
                 return 1;
             }

    Q_ASSERT( QSslSocket::supportsSsl() );

    MainWindow w;
    QPixmap pixmap(":/splash/splash.png");
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap,Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

        w.setWindowOpacity(0);
        w.setWindowTitle("Cyto Viewer " + CSM_VERSION);

        splash.show();
        QEventLoop loop;
        MyInitThread *thread = new MyInitThread();
        QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
        QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), &splash, SLOT(close()));
        QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), &w, SLOT(slInit()));
        thread->start();
        loop.exec();
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

        ui->setupUi(this);
connect(view->page()->networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )),
                               this, SLOT(onSslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )));

}
```

**SSL errors slot**

```
void MainWindow::onSslErrors(QNetworkReply* reply, const QList<QSslError> &errors)
{
    if(SSL_ONCE != true){
        QString errorString;
        bool firstError = false;
            //TODO: Get this displaying cirtificate errors
            foreach (const QSslError e, errors)
            {
                if(firstError != true) {
                    if (!errorString.isEmpty())
                        errorString += "";
                    if(e.error() != e.NoError){
                        errorString +=  "<ul style=\"background: url(minus-small.png);\"><li style=\"background: url(minus-small.png);\">" + e.errorString() + "</li></ul>";

                    }
                }

            }
            //Delay MessageBox until the splash screen closes (2 seconds)
            //delay(2.5);
            QEventLoop loop;
            MainWinThread *thread = new MainWinThread();
               connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
               //Detect any SSL errors from the network reply
               thread->start();
               loop.exec(); //Do event processing until the thread has finished!
            QMessageBox sslQuestion;
             //Fix for QMessageBox width
            QSpacerItem horizontalSpacer(500, 0, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

                    sslQuestion.setText("Cyto Viewer " + CSM_VERSION);
                    QGridLayout* layout = (QGridLayout*)sslQuestion.layout();
                    sslQuestion.setInformativeText("The following SSL error(s) occured: " + errorString + "Do you wish to continue?");
                    sslQuestion.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
                    sslQuestion.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/logo/lock-ssl.png"));
                    sslQuestion.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::No);
                    sslQuestion.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
                    sslQuestion.setMinimumWidth(800);
                    layout->addItem(&horizontalSpacer, layout->rowCount(), 0, 1, layout->columnCount());
                    int SSLChoice = sslQuestion.exec();

                if (SSLChoice == QMessageBox::No) {
                    reply->abort();
                    delete systray;
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                    //qApp->quit();
                    //return;
                } else {
                    reply->ignoreSslErrors(/*errors*/);
                    SSL_ONCE = true;                    
                }
    } else {
        reply->ignoreSslErrors();
        return;
    }
}
```

**My slinit slot (for setting up system tray/hidingmain window)**

```
void MainWindow::slInit()
{    
    setWindowOpacity(1);
    //Set min size, this can be changed through registry
    this->setMinimumSize(800, 640);
    //System tray
    aboutAction = new QAction("About", this);
    quitAction = new QAction("Exit", this);
    connect (aboutAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(about()));
    connect (quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
    trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
    trayIconMenu->addAction(aboutAction);
    //trayIconMenu->addAction(printAction);
    trayIconMenu->addAction(quitAction);

    systray = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    connect(systray, SIGNAL(messageClicked()), this, SLOT(messageClicked()));
    QIcon icon(":/logo/csm.ico");
    systray->setIcon(icon);
    systray->setContextMenu (trayIconMenu);
    systray->show();
    if(systray->isVisible() /*&& !csmURL.isEmpty()*/){;
        QString cdate = QDate::currentDate().toString("yyyy");
        trayMsg = "<qt>Cyto Viewer "+CSM_VERSION+" is a browser produced by Perceptive Instruments&copy; " + cdate + " specifically for Cyto Study Manager</b>.</qt>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should be declaring window after the splash screen?

Comment: Declaring the MainWindow class after I destroy my splash screen seem to fix it.